# Display all the bins on sns distplot

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

I have dataframe which has values ranging from 0 to 100 in each column and I am trying to create a distplot with frquency of each value.

sample dataframe (df) is as follows

```
df = {'a':[90.45,90.2,91.55,96.84,89.68,94.06,96.26,94.88,85.00,98.35,88.80,94.62,96.94,91.79],
      'b':[89.48,89.47,89.48,89.48,89.48,89.23,98.26,90.46,97.27,94.85,92.45,94.85,99.47,101.17]}
```

I have tried below code

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np

x = [['a','b']]


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 1,constrained_layout=True)    
axes = axes.flatten()         
fig.set_size_inches(10, 15)
#fig.tight_layout()

for ax, col in zip(axes, x.columns):
    sns.distplot(x, ax = ax,bins= [90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100],width=1,
             kde=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(90, 101, 1))
```

but when I display the plot the bin sizes are still showing with intervals of 2. I want to diplay all the bins with size of 1

[image]

Comment: The bin size is one. The *ticks* are at multiples of 2.

Comment: I want ticks to dispaly at evry 1 unit instead of 2

Comment: `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))`.  Note that in your `for`loop you need to put `ax.set_xticklabels(range(90, 101, 1))` inside `for ax, col in zip(axes, x.columns):`, not after

Comment: @johanC if I put this ax.set_xticklabels(range(90, 101, 1)) inside for loop. It just gives me the plot for the last column in the loop